# Lazy load images of different dimensions in UIScrollView without paging

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a horizontal scrolling UIScrollView which should display images of different dimensions next to each other. All images would have to be resized to the height of the scrollview, which leaves us with a variable width. The problem here is that there is no paging, but images still need to be lazily loaded. To make things worse, at the time the view is being displayed I only have URL's for the images, so I have no idea about width/height of the images.

My idea would be to have a fixed-size container view in the scrollview for each URL. Then let the container view load the image and tell the scrollview about the size of the image via a delegate. The scrollview could then change the size of the container view and relayout the other views accordingly. (But isn't it so that you can't do this *while* scrolling?)

I'm not sure if this is the way to go, would love to hear some thoughts on this. Also, how would I actually determine when to load an image? Contentsize and offsets of the scrollview would change constantly. I also haven't seen any sample code or open source projects that do this, if I missed them, please let me know.

Comment: This seems like a perfect use case for a collection view. Why not use one of those?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way would be to load a small JSON file (or other format) at start, with just the sizes of images in it. Then you'd know all sizes in advance.

This is very to do on the server side with GD or Imagick (at least with PHP), just don't forget to cache the results on the server for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Contentsize changing is not a problem for UIScrollView i think. You only have to make sure the current placeholder that takes most of the screen estate stays on the same position. Changing the scrollviews contentoffset to keep him om the same position. If there are more is 1 placeholder fully on screen i would take the left one if the user dragged to the left en the right one if the user dragged to the right.

Please tell me if i misunderstood.